# Can I show hyperlinks in AutoCompleteExtender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

I'm able to create a List<> of strings and show it in a AutoCompleteExtender, but how can I make these suggestions clickable links? I figured, I could create a List of HyperLink objects, but they just show up as [Object]  in the list. Any suggestions?

In simple words, I want to be able to click suggestions from the AutoSuggest list.

Will I need to use some kinda client side script?

Comment: Have you tried returning an anchor HTML as the string for your items?

Comment: Have you tried using <a href=''>Suggestion</a> in text property?

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. :( The suggestions just show up with raw html. Not as clickable links.

Comment: The service method I'm using returns a array of strings. I tried making these strings html markup for a href and that didn't work.

Comment: I think you have to use Javascript in your page check this link it may help you
[Auto Complete with Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1716806.aspx/1?AutoCompleteExtender%20to%20link%20results%20to%20page)